# Magento2 $block->getChildHtml() error in nginx?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have custom template, referenced in the .xml file below:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Sample\ABC\Block\Adminhtml\Demo\Edit" name="demo.parent" template="Sample_Demo::parent.phtml">
      <block class="Sample\ABC\Block\Adminhtml\Demo\Edit\Child" name="demo.child" template="Sample_Demo::parent\child.phtml" /> 
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

in `parent.phtml` I call **(1)** `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('demo.child'); ?>`

in localhost (Windows) it **runs fine**. But when I upload it to my **nginx server it doens't run**.

I change  **(1)** to

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Sample\ABC\Block\Adminhtml\Demo\Edit\Child')->setTemplate('Sample_Demo::parent\child.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

and **it runs**.

Please tell me what's the difference and what could be the solution to fix (1).

Comment: May be issue in your template="Sample_Demo::parent\child.phtml" you have to set like template="Sample_Demo::parent/child.phtml"

Comment: I have updated my answer. you can close this question after mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml you have issue regarding **slash(/)**,

For Template declaration using xml you have to use `Forward Slash(/)`

For Block or any class declaration you have to use `Backward Slash(\)`

In your xml,

Replace `template="Sample_Demo::parent\child.phtml"`

With `template="Sample_Demo::parent/child.phtml"`